# What does breathing through the mouth have to do with cracked lips?

Tags: human-biology

https://www.healthline.com/health/mouth-breathing#symptoms3

> Symptoms in children
>
> Children who breathe through their mouths for most of the day may also have the following symptoms:
> ...
> ...
> dry, cracked lips
> ...

Why can breathing through mouth result in dry, cracked lips?

Comment: Breath is humid. Constant addition to humidity to lips and then the drying of that humidity will dry up the lips, similar (but not as quickly) as licking the lips does.

Comment: breath varies in humidity and with temperature. lips crack fairly easily. increased airflow can cause dehydration. it's vague guidelines

Answer (score 1):

You may notice waking up with chapped lips at times. It may be because of sleeping with your mouth open. So, of course you breathe through your mouth all night, leaving it exposed to continuous flow of your breath. Continuous airflow around the mouth region can cause chapped lips in many individuals.